# Reaching zero-g experience on a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

There is a commercial flight that you can take and experience zero-g. Here is the graph that they provide with data. I wonder how and why zero-g happens.

Can you help me understand this? It looks similar to the International Space Station experience but how can we maintain zero-g on a plane in terms of acceleration, lift force and drag?

[image]

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554356/123208 & the question it links to.